# How to find X where Y is equal to Z in dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

In javascript, one can use "find" or "findIndex" to extract the object`{ "src": "findThis", "type": "the right one" }` from

```json
{ "results": [ 
      { "src": "findThat", "type": "not the right one" }, 
      { "src": "findThis", "type": "the right one" }
 ] 
}
```

How would i do this in python?

Comment: You'd have to write a loop. Can you please show what you've attempted so far?

Comment: Im trying to use list#index but i have no idea so thanks for the idea! ill try now

Comment: do you want to extract items by matching `src`, or matching `type`, or both?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit unclear as to what the actual data structure looks like in Python. Based on the example as written I'm assuming you have an array of dictionaries.

```
data = [{"src": "findThat", "type": "not the right one" }, 
      { "src": "findThis", "type": "the right one" }]
```

In this case you can use a loop, but it is more "pythonic" to use a comprehension.

```
filtered = [a for a in data if a["src"] == "findThis"]
```

Or more generically,

```
key, value = "src", "find this"
filtered = [a for a in data if a[key] == value]
```

You could also use the `filter` function with a lambda function but adding that complexity seems unnecessary here.